# Does not work method Selection.removeRange()

Tags: javascript

**HTML:**

```
<p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui aliquam quod aperiam veniam animi. Debitis iure sit incidunt sint dicta enim voluptatum inventore itaque cumque error. Neque voluptatem beatae fuga?</span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui aliquam quod aperiam veniam animi. Debitis iure sit incidunt sint dicta enim voluptatum inventore itaque cumque error. Neque voluptatem beatae fuga?</span>
</p>

<button>Remove range</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var p = document.body.firstElementChild;

var rng, selectText;

p.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    rng = document.createRange();
    rng.selectNodeContents(p);
    selectText = window.getSelection();
    selectText.addRange(rng);
}, false);


document.body.lastElementChild.addEventListener('click', function() {
    selectText.removeRange(rng);
}, false);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ganL0po/)

I can not understand why the method does not work Selection.removeRange()? The idea is to remain only the original selection.

Answer (score 1):

In `safari` and `google-chrome`, you should use

```
selectText.removeAllRanges(rng)
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51ht0vv5/1/)

Comment: Thank you. Is not two different method?